# Looping through an array of objects and filter using a key

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a nested array of objects as below

```
const person = [
   {
     firstName: 'Alex',
     secondName: 'Lexi',
     address: [
       { place: 'California'},
       { pin: 1233 }
     ]
  },

{
     firstName: 'Max',
     secondName: 'Lui',
     address: [
       { place: 'New York' },
       { pin: 3455 }
     ]
  }   
]
```

I would like to loop through the array and get the address object corresponding to the firstName 'Max'.

I can use this data to generate links and their sublinks (on clicking the links)

I have attempted the following

```
const renderPerson = () => {
  person.forEach((item) => {
    return item.firstName;
  })
}

const renderAddress = () => {
   person.forEach((item) => {
     if(item.firstName === "Max" {
        return item.address;
  }
}
}
```

Then

```
const html = `<li>${renderPerson()}</li>`;

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
```

But it returns undefined. How can solve it?

Comment: You can use `filter()` to retrieve only the objects within an array matching certain property values. Note that this will return an array though, so you need to either build a string from that array, or return a single specific object from it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I am trying to extract address objects if firstName === 'Max'

Comment: Then you can use `find()` and extract the data after you found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look up array [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

It would look something like this:

```js
const person = [
  {
    firstName: "Alex",
    secondName: "Lexi",
    address: [{ place: "California" }, { pin: 1233 }],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Max",
    secondName: "Lui",
    address: [{ place: "New York" }, { pin: 3455 }],
  },
];

const myPerson = person.find(p => p.firstName === "Max");
console.log(myPerson?.address); // [{place: "New York"}, {pin: 3455}]
```

Comment: yeah, i guess you're right. find would return the object directly or undefined, making it easier to check if it actually found something. kinda slipped my mind that find is a thing :D